# Porting LibreOffice spreadsheet to pdfLaTeX: output no longer fits in one page

Tags: spacing, pdftex, formatting, line-spacing, libre-office

I have a 4x4 Sudoku template that was created in LibreOffice Calc. The following is the list of all settings that I modified in the spreadsheet.

```
Format > Page...
    Page
        Paper Format
            1. Format: A4 (210mm x 297mm)
            2. Orientation: Portrait
        Margins
            3. Left: 2.6mm
            4. Right: 2.6mm
            5. Top: 2.6mm
            6. Bottom: 2.6mm
        Layout Settings
            7. Page numbers: None
            8. Table alignment: Horizontal & Vertical
    Header
        9. No Header
    Footer
        10. No Footer

Cells
    Cells comprising each puzzle
        11-a. Font size: 20pt
        11-b. Font: Liberation Sans
        12. Column Width 11mm
        13. Row Height 11mm
        14. Align Center
        15. Center Vertically
    Cells acting as space between adjacent puzzles
        16. Column Width 4mm
        17. Row Height 4mm
    Borders
        18. Exterior of each 2x2 Square 2pt
        19. Interior of each 2x2 square 0.75pt
```

These changes allowed me to fit 24 4x4 Sudokus in one A4 paper as shown here. The math below confirms that it should not overflow.

Horizontal: (Puzzles) 11 x 4 x 4 + (Spaces between puzzles) 4 x 3 + (Left & Right margins) 2.6 x 2 = 193.2 < 210

Vertical: (Puzzles) 11 x 4 x 6 + (Spaces between puzzles) 4 x 5 + (Top & Bottom margins) 2.6 x 2 = 289.2 < 297
[image: Fig 1. Output of spreadsheet]

I decided to port this to pdfLaTeX and tried to preserve as many features as possible. I thought I did everything except applying Liberation Sans, a TrueType font which I don't know how to apply in pdfLaTeX.

However when I compile the source code below only 20 puzzles fit in one page. The last line of four puzzles are pushed to the last page. This might be due to the fact that I changed `\arraystretch` to adjust the height of the cells which may not have exactly amounted to 11mm. Also the horizontal gaps and vertical gaps seem unequal in the PDF output so I may have not changed all spacing properly.

[image: Fig 2. Output of pdfLaTeX file]

How should I change this code so that the spacing is exactly the same as the spreadsheet version? If possible, how do I change the font to Liberation Sans? Finally, an attempt to shorten the code by using `\newvertical` failed. I get the error `` ! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\newvertical): `c' used. `` when I replace `@{\vrule width 2pt}` with `\newvertical{2}`. Why does it fail while `\newhorizontal` works?

```
% 11-a. Font 20pt
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{extsizes}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% Substitute font since Liberation is TrueType
\usepackage{lmodern}

% 1. Format: A4
% 2. Orientation: Portrait
% 3, 4, 5, 6. Margins: Left, Right, Top, Bottom 2.6mm
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2.6mm, bottom=2.6mm, left=2.6mm, right=2.6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
% 14, 15. Align Center & Center Vertically
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
% Prevent indents
\noindent

% 9, 10. No Header & Footer
\pagestyle{empty}
% 7. Page numbers: None
\pagenumbering{gobble} 

% 13. Row Height 11mm (Have no idea if this is exactly 11mm)
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.35}

% Commands to shorten code - \newvertical does not work
\newcommand\newvertical[1]{@{\vrule width #1pt}}
\newcommand\newhorizontal[1]{\noalign{\hrule height #1pt}}

% Disables implicit vertical space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

% 8. Table alignment: Horizontal & Vertical
\begin{center}

    % 18. Exterior of each 2x2 Square 2pt
    % 19. Interior of each 2x2 square 0.75pt
    % 12. Column Width 11mm
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    % 16. Column Width 4mm
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}

    % 17. Row Height 4mm
    \vspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 0.75pt} M{11mm} @{\vrule width 2pt} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! This is a good first question but what's the motive? Why use pdfLaTeX to produce output identical to what you already have in LibreOffice? Note that 20pt means different things in different fonts, so switching font will throw your calculations off completely. You can use Liberation Sans if you switch engine (XeTeX or LuaTeX) or you find or create support files for Liberation Sans. If you're not sure whether you want to do the latter, trust me, you don't. (I probably would, but I'm stubborn.) So consider the former if you really want this.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to produce identical output to LibreOffice is for the birds. The only reason to do this is typically some institutional requirement e.g. a journal which insists submissions must look as if produced in Word.

There are two ways to use a true type font. One is to use an alternative engine (XeTeX or LuaTeX). The other is to acquire or create support files for pdfTeX. Unless you know how to do the latter or fancy the challenge, you want to do the former or, failing that, pick a different font.

I used XeTeX to produce output which is not identical to what you'll get with LibreOffice but which does fit 20 puzzles on the page with reasonable-looking spacing. I'm still getting a bad box with this, but I'm not immediately sure what to do about it, so I've left it.

[image: 20 puzzles on A4 in Liberation Sans]

I've let LaTeX figure out the vertical spacing. I see no advantage to setting this explicitly. LaTeX is better at this than me (but not so great it doesn't push the last row out of the text area, though this may be `geometry`'s fault or, more likely, my lack of facility with `geometry`). I've used `\extrarowheight` to approximate the 11mm, but this could probably be improved, and a new column type instead of the `\newvertical{#1}` macro. Uncomment the commented `geometry` line to get more information about what `geometry` is (or claims to be) doing.

```
\documentclass[20pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{extsizes}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}

% 1. Format: A4
% 2. Orientation: Portrait
% 3, 4, 5, 6. Margins: Left, Right, Top, Bottom 2.6mm
% \usepackage[margin=2.6mm,headheight=0pt,noheadfoot,marginpar=0pt,marginparsep=0pt,showframe,verbose]{geometry}
\usepackage[margin=2.6mm,headheight=0pt,noheadfoot,marginpar=0pt,marginparsep=0pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}
% 14, 15. Align Center & Center Vertically
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
% Commands to shorten code - \newvertical does not work
% create a new column type instead of trying to use a standard macro
\newcolumntype{V}[1]{@{\vrule width #1pt}}
\newcommand\newhorizontal[1]{\noalign{\hrule height #1pt}}%
\begin{document}
% Prevent indents
\noindent
%
% 9, 10. No Header & Footer
\pagestyle{empty}%
% 7. Page numbers: None
\pagenumbering{gobble}%
%
% 13. Row Height 11mm (Have no idea if this is exactly 11mm)
% \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.35}%
\setlength\extrarowheight{11mm}%
\addtolength\extrarowheight{-\baselineskip}%
%
% Disables implicit vertical space between paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
%
% 8. Table alignment: Horizontal & Vertical
% \begin{center}
\centering
    % 18. Exterior of each 2x2 Square 2pt
    % 19. Interior of each 2x2 square 0.75pt
    % 12. Column Width 11mm
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    % 16. Column Width 4mm
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}\vfill

    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}\vfill

    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}\vfill

    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}\vfill

    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}\vfill

    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4mm}%
    \begin{tabular}{ V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} M{11mm} V{0.75} M{11mm} V{2} }
        \newhorizontal{2}
        1 & 2 &  & 4 \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
         &  & 1 &  \\ \newhorizontal{2}
         &  &  &  \\ \newhorizontal{0.75}
        4 &  &  & 3 \\ \newhorizontal{2}
    \end{tabular}\vfill

    \mbox{ }
\end{document}
```